# Operation not allowed: alter table add columns(line 1, pos 0)

Tags: apache-spark, hive

We have `Spark 2.1`, `Thrift JDBC/ODBC` server configured with `Hive 2.1.1` and using `Beeline`.

DDL statements like

> CREATE TABLE, CREATE TABLE LIKE, CREATE TABLE LIKE, ALTER TABLE SET
>   TBLPROPERTIES

works well.

But `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMNS` fails

```
create table tbl1 (id int, c1 string, c2 string);
alter table tbl1 add columns (c3 string);
```

> Error: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: Operation
>   not allowed: alter table add columns(line 1, pos 0)
>
> == SQL == alter table tbl1 add columns (c3 string) ^^^ (state=,code=0)

Any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is work in progress for Spark v2.x

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19261

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, hence I'm adding it as a possible answer here, was to use hive directly from the console, all `ALTER TABLE` statements worked like a charm (we are on Spark 2.0.2 with not much rush to upgrade...).

Answer (score -1):

Try using HiveContext instead of spark Session. As some of the hive metastore queries does on work well with spark Session.