# How can I update/delete data in Spark-hive?

Tags: java, scala, hive, apache-spark-sql, spark-hive

I don't think my title can explain the problem so  here is the problem:

Details build.sbt:

```
name := "Hello"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
version      := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

Code:

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().appName("HiveOnSpark").master("local").getOrCreate()
val hiveql : HiveContext  = new HiveContext(sparkSession.sparkContext);

hiveql.sql("drop table if exists test")
hiveql.sql("create table test (id int, name string) stored as orc tblproperties(\"transactional\"=\"true\")")
hiveql.sql("insert into test values(1,'Yash')")
hiveql.sql("insert into test values(2,'Yash')")
hiveql.sql("insert into test values(3,'Yash')")
hiveql.sql("select * from test").show()
hiveql.sql("delete from test where id= 1")
```

Problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
Operation not allowed: delete from(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
delete from test where id= 1
^^^

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.operationNotAllowed(ParserUtils.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:925)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder$$anonfun$visitFailNativeCommand$1.apply(SparkSqlParser.scala:916)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:916)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlAstBuilder.visitFailNativeCommand(SparkSqlParser.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.SqlBaseParser$FailNativeCommandContext.accept(SqlBaseParser.java:952)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:42)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder$$anonfun$visitSingleStatement$1.apply(AstBuilder.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParserUtils$.withOrigin(ParserUtils.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AstBuilder.visitSingleStatement(AstBuilder.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser$$anonfun$parsePlan$1.apply(ParseDriver.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:699)
at main.scala.InitMain$.delayedEndpoint$main$scala$InitMain$1(InitMain.scala:41)
at main.scala.InitMain$delayedInit$body.apply(InitMain.scala:9)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at main.scala.InitMain$.main(InitMain.scala:9)
at main.scala.InitMain.main(InitMain.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Same Problem with update query.

So now as I have gone through [This](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6007/can-we-use-updatedelete-queries-in-databricks-with.html), [This](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/23836/spark-sql-update-command.html), [update query in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517371/update-query-in-spark-sql),[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062427/operation-not-allowed-alter-table-add-columnsline-1-pos-0/42394017), [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062427/operation-not-allowed-alter-table-add-columnsline-1-pos-0) and many others.

I have come to know that Spark doesn't support update/delete but I am in a situation that need to use these both the operations. Can anyone suggest/help somehow.

Comment: have you tried update/delete through a jdbc connection?

Answer (score 0):

A not very performant work-around would be to

1. Load your existing data (I would suggest to use the DataFrame API)
2. Create new DataFrame with updated/deleted records
3. rewrite the DataFrame to disk

Choosing an appropriate partitioning for the Hive-Table could minimize the amount of data to be re-written.

Comment: Yeah That can be a solution for small warehouse but what if I have a warehouse of 300000 records and 20 need  to be deleted and 10 to be updated. I don't think in this case anyone would prefer rewriting the whole dataframe.

Comment: Yeah I know that and I am using it exactly, but there must be another gate to it. I am looking for that way.

Comment: And you yourself have mentioned that it is "A not very performant work-around would be to".

Comment: @yashpalbharadwaj and you yourself mentioned that it's not possible with spark :) so feel free to use another solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use LLAP library to enable update and delete.