# Spark - Operation not allowed: alter table replace columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.2, apache-spark-2.3

Looks like hive `replace columns` is not working with spark 2.2.1 and also with 2.3.1

```
alterSchemaSql : alter table myschema.mytable replace columns (a int,b int,d int)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
Operation not allowed: alter table replace columns(line 2, pos 6)
```

Looks like it's been fixed for `ADD COLUMNS` 2.2 version onwards. It also works for me but `replace columns` still fails.

[Operation not allowed: alter table add columns(line 1, pos 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062427/operation-not-allowed-alter-table-add-columnsline-1-pos-0)

Following docs says it should be supported. Not sure why it's failing for me.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/alter-table-or-view.html#replace-columns

Comment: Do you mean rename column or replace column?

Comment: replace column.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems `ALTER TABLE table REPLACE` is not implemented by Spark.

Take a look at `SparkSqlParser.scala`: [SparkSqlParser.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5e3520f7f49a66dd6639b6e5383a33fdb9e2f27d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkSqlParser.scala)

There, you can see, what SQL statements work with Spark.